# Calculating Trailing Twelve Months Revenue on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
yyyymm Revenue
 ...    ...    
201701  450   
201701  600    
201702  350    
...     ...
201903   559
```

I want a query that returns in the following form:

```
yyyymm  TTM Revenue
 201701   Sum of Revenue from 201601 to 201612
 201702   Sum of Revenue from 201602 to 201701
 ...      ...
```

I tried to use:

```
select yyyymm, sum(case when ...) from table group by 1
```

But I'm unable to figure out the logic and syntax. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use a subselect (I called your table `foo`):

```
select
    foo.*,
    (select sum(revenue) from
        foo ly
    where
        ly.yyyymm between foo.yyyymm - 100 and foo.yyyymm - 1
    ) as last_years_revenue
from foo;
```

This produces the following result:

Input:

```
 yyyymm | revenue
--------+---------
 201701 |     450
 201701 |     600
 201702 |     350
 201601 |      45
 201601 |      60
 201602 |      35


 yyyymm | revenue | last_years_revenue
--------+---------+--------------------
 201701 |     450 |                140
 201701 |     600 |                140
 201702 |     350 |               1085
 201601 |      45 |               NULL
 201601 |      60 |               NULL
 201602 |      35 |                105
```

2016's revenue is 60+35+45 = 140.

2017-02's revenue is 450+600+35 = 1085.

Answer (score 0):

You want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(revenue) over (order by yyyymm rows between 12 preceding and 1 preceding) as trailing_12_months_revenue
from t;
```

This takes the trailing 12 months *in the data* (as written).  If you are missing months, it can be modified for that.

Comment: This will only work however if there are no gaps in the months

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you any or not, but this would be the approach for Microsoft Sql Server, minus the 12 month part of the equation, which would be a little bit of work in T-Sql if the date is stored in this format to cast it as a date and run a where over that date.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (yyyymm int, revenue int)

INSERT INTO #temp
(
    yyyymm,
    revenue
)
VALUES
(201701, 450), (201701, 600), (201702,350)

SELECT 
    yyyymm, 
    SUM(revenue) 
From #temp 
GROUP BY #temp.yyyymm 

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Note that the CREATE, INSERT, and DROP are only to have sample data to work from. The select is what you will care about.